# CodeIgniter to Symfony2 with Doctrine2

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm really having a hard time converting this query to Doctrine:

```
public function get_order($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_orderline');
    $this->db->join('tbl_order', 'tbl_order.orderNo = tbl_orderline.orderNo');
    $this->db->join('tbl_customer', 'tbl_customer.customerNo = tbl_order.customerNo');
    $this->db->join('tbl_product', 'tbl_product.productNo = tbl_orderline.productNo');
    $this->db->where('tbl_order.orderNo', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Could you please help me with this? 
Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Your entities are already mapped? The relations that you use to join are present in the mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// if you're currently in custom Repository class then:
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ol');

// if you're in a controller, then should be:
$qb = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:OrderLine')->createQueryBuilder('ol'); // Or whatever your bundle name is.

// query alias legend:

// ol - order line
// o - order
// c - customer
// p - product

// Your query builder should look something like this:

$qb
    ->addSelect('o, c, p')
    ->leftJoin('ol.order', 'o') // this is your relation with [order]
    ->leftJoin('o.customer', 'c') // this is your relation with [customer] from [order]
    ->leftJoin('ol.product', 'p') // this is your relation with [product] from [order line]
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('ol.id', ':orderLineId')
    ->setParameter('orderLineId', $id)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

**Note:**

Since you did not provide any entity mappings, this is completely out of the blue. You are most likely going to change the properties in this query, but at the very least, it should give you the start you need.

Don't hesitate to ask, if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 1):

Ive always found it easier to write in straight [dql](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).  Trying to use the querybuilder for complex stuff drives me nuts.  This obviously requires you to have the correct relationships mapped in your entities, either annotated or with an orm file.

Obviously its hard to test what Ive put below, so you may need to debug a little.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
'select orderline, order, customer, product
from BundleName:tlb_orderline orderline
join orderline.orderNo order
join order.customerNo customer
join orderline.productNo product
where order.orderNo = :id');

$query->setParameter('id' => $id);

return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: are there other ways? i mean i'm not using dql with my codes, i think will not look good if i mixed my codes with dql.

Comment: but your post title says youre using doctrine2 (which IS dql)?  Youve got 2 answers now using both methods.  Both should do the job.